# Another way to insert with an Id, but with out updating the Identity seed

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have two tables, an old and a new (the old will be replaced by the new), both tables will and are being used.

We will migrate items over but some processes still use the old table and cannot be swapped over right away, so we want to create a "dummy item" in the old table using the new tables data, so we can utilize some old processes.

We want to insert the dummy items above at 500000 but keep the seed of the OLD table id below the 500000

Test table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OLD]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RowNumber] [int] NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[OLD] ([RowNumber])
VALUES (1), (2)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT OLD ON

INSERT INTO OLD (id, [RowNumber])
VALUES (500000, 500000)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT OLD OFF

-- -- Uncomment for the reseeding
-- DECLARE @Reseed AS INT
-- SET     @Reseed = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM OLD WHERE ID < 500000)
-- DBCC CHECKIDENT('OLD', RESEED,@Reseed)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[OLD] ([RowNumber])
VALUES (3)

SELECT * 
FROM old

DROP TABLE [dbo].[OLD]
```

Current data

| Id | RowNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

So inserting, with out IDENTITY_INSERT, RowNumber 500003 after the 500000 IDENTITY_INSERT and have the Id automagically be the old seed.

Looking for:

| Id | RowNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 500000 | 500000 |
| 3 | 500003 |

I looked into reseeding but feel it could be quite dangerous, and the NOT FOR REPLICATION seems to be only for the SQL Server replication. Is there another way that doesn't feel as dangerous?

Comment: Insert your dummy data into a different table, and the use a `VIEW` that `UNION (ALL)`s the data?

Comment: Won't be able to as we would need to migrate data over to the new table, but we pivoted and have a column that is referencing the old table id and starting the new Id from scratch.